# MySQL insert data containing single and double quotes giving a syntax error

Tags: mysql, insert, quotes

I am using the following insert statement within a tool pulling data from one DB into another one.

```
INSERT INTO act_vulnerabilities_internal_test (device_type, ip_address, user_tag,       
repositoryID, severity, pluginID, pluginName, pluginText)

VALUES ("@Data.device_type~", "@Data.ip_address~", "@Data.user_tag~",    
"@Data.repositoryID~", "@Data.severity~", "@Data.pluginID~", "@Data.pluginName~",   
 @Data.pluginText~)
```

Error message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\nSynopsis :\n\nIt is possible to retrieve file backups from the remote web serv' at line 3

The data I am trying to pull from one of the columns has a lot of single and double quotes in it (this is pulling from a proprietary tool and I cannot edit the data). The column giving me the problems is the one named pluginText. Is there a way to make the db ignore the ' and " contained within the rows?

Is mysql_real_escape_string what I need to do this properly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update**: Do it with the [`QUOTE()` function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_quote).

*Original answer:*

Please try this:

```
INSERT INTO 
...
VALUES (
...
, REPLACE(@Data.pluginText, '"', '\"')
)
```

or if you have single *and* double quotes in it:

```
INSERT INTO 
...
VALUES (
...
, REPLACE(REPLACE(@Data.pluginText, '"', '\"'), "'", "\'")
)
```

You can read more about it [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-literals.html)

Comment: I tried both and receive a similar error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Thorough tests" was not enabled\nwhen this scan was run.\n\nCVE : CVE-99,' at line 3                                                                                    Do I also need to remove the .  \  - and : symbols?

Comment: @user1208132 Can you give me the text that's causing the trouble so I can test around a little?

Comment: Here it is, exactly how it is formatted and has to remain: "Thorough tests" was not enabled\nwhen this scan was run.\n\nCVE : CVE-2012-2100,

Comment: Does anyone have a take on this?

Comment: @user1208132 Sorry, I forgot about that question. Edited my answer, now there are just single backslashes. Don't know how I mixed two of them in there. Now it should work. Also added a link where you can find more information.

Answer (score 5):

We need to use the `addslashes($text)` function to escape all single quotes and double quotes, NULL, etc. to make it understandable by MYSQL.
[Here is some information on that.](https://ahmsaiful.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/insert-string-with-single-quote-or-double-quote-in-mysql/)